# Cypress : How to verify the font color is not be as expected one

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress, bdd, chai

I have to validate the font color as red for some set of condition. So that, I have implemented the below assertion for achieving that,

```
return cy.xpath(`xpathcondition`)
    .should('have.css','-webkit-text-fill-color','rgb(208, 25, 71)')
```

Its worked for me.

The same thing I have to validate it should not be red for some other set of condition. Could anyone suggest me how to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `not` assertion.

```js
cy.xpath(xpathcondition).should(
  'not.have.css',
  '-webkit-text-fill-color',
  'rgb(208, 25, 71)'
)
```